# How to model a doctor and patient appointments in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails and stackoverflow beginner here so please pardon me for any mistakes.

I am developing an appointment booking system between doctors and patients. Now, the flow goes like this A doctor will create its available time slots and the patients can see the available time slots of a particular doctor and can book the time slot.

```
class Doctor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :availabilities
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Availibilities < ApplicationRecord
  #table columns:  id | start_date | start_time | end_date | end_time | slot_taken(boolean) 
  belongs_to :doctor
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :doctors, through:appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :doctor
end
```

Now, how do I connect the patient to the availabilities model? How can I make a relationship which will fetch me which doctor's slots the patient has booked?
Any other method through which I can achieve the above relationships/ functionality?

Also correct me if the above relationships are wrong.

Comment: I would take off the availability model completely and use appointment model instead. Appointment is based on the availability of the doctor,isn't it?

Comment: @Pavan The basic requirement is that the doctors themselves should be able to create the available time slot. For example a doctor should be able to create that he is available from 08:00 to 08:30 on 12th July, and then he is available from 08:45 to 09:15 on 12th July. That is why I created the availability model where even doctors can see whether the slot is booked or not. I hope u got the gist. Is it redundant?

Comment: Agree with @Pavan, you could eliminate the availability model and consider an appointment booked if it has an associated patient. In your Appointment model you could create a method that returns the availability status, e.g. self.patient.nil?

Comment: @CChandler81 Then how will the doctors be allowed to create the time slots?

Comment: @CChandler81 If I remove the availibility model then, I need to add start_time and end_time to the appointments table. Now, when the patients book that slot a patient_id will be associated with it and as u said I can check if the patient is nil then slot is vailable else not available. Is it correct?

Comment: Yep! You could create scopes in your Appointment model for available vs. booked (e.g. scope :available, -> { where(patient_id: nil) }) and then allow the patients to only see the available ones while the doctors can see both.

Comment: @CChandler81 Got it! Thank you very much for clearing out.