# How to update has_many :through table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

This is a follow up question from one of my earlier questions: [How to Model doctor and patient relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062049/how-to-model-a-doctor-and-patient-appointments-in-rails)
I am fairly new to rails, I am making an appointment booking system between patient and doctor, I have made the relationships, set up authentication using devise. I have 3 models:

```
class Doctor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :doctors, through:appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  #table_columns: id | start_time| end_time| doctor_id| patient_id|slot_taken|
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :doctor
end
```

I have created the appointments controller: Some actions are below:

```
#current_doctor comes from devise. Have created two separate models for doctor and patients using devise

def create
  @appointment = current_doctor.appointments.build(appointment_params) 
  respond_to do |format|
    if @appointment.save
      format.html { redirect_to appointments_path, notice: 'Appointment was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :new } 
    end
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @appointment.update(appointment_params)
      format.html { redirect_to appointments_path, notice: 'Appointment was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render :edit } 
    end
  end
end

private
  def appointment_params
    params.require(:meeting).permit(start_time, end_time)
  end
```

As you can see, the doctor can create the time slots of when he is available, and can edit,update and destroy the same for him/herself and when he creates one the appointment table gets updated with doctor_id, start_time and end_time.

Now, what should I do to add the patient_id and change slot_taken to true (default: false) to it? When the patient books the available slot, the appointments table should be updated with patient_id and slot_taken value. How should I update the appointments table and where should I put the code for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, some advice: I don't think two user models it's a good idea. Think it would be best have one `User` devise model, and that user have an `Role` associated for it, so you control the access type by that. If you have to add more type of users to that system, creating one model for each one can be troubling.

About the appointments, question, in a roughly way, if you have an `doctor` instance, and you wanna make an appointment for some patient at `s` start_time and `e` end_time, you can do something like:

```
doctor.appointments.find_by(start_time: s, end_time: e).update(patient_id: your_patient_id)
```

About where to put that, depends on how your system works. Is the client that assigns himself? Or some administrator does that?
Anyway, think you should have another action/view for doing that assignment, so you can have a form where the user can input that information, and when he sends the form, you handle it and do the update in some way like a showed before.

Hope this helps, good luck

Comment: For example let's say doctor A is there and he has created the time slot available on 13th July 08:00 AM to 09:00 AM. Now on the patient side, in the form the patient can see that doctor A is available on 13th July 08:00 AM to 09:00 AM. He clicks on the book button and the patient_id should get updated. And I am passing doctor_id with the book button. Now, my question is should I pass it to the same update method inside appointments table?

Comment: you can reuse that update method. Since I believe the form you present to the patient already contains the doctor_id, start_time and end_time informations (you have those informations previously), the only information you'll need to get is the patient_id information, that you can get inside the update method, by the current_user (in your case current_patient)

Comment: Ok thanks. It works now. I didn't know whether it was good practice or not whether the update method should be access like that or not. I will also change to one model as you suggested.

Comment: I second that. Managing an app at scale with two different models that serve the same purpose becomes a nightmare and is ultimately just creating technical debt. ;)